# How do I recreate a clustered index on another column in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, indexing, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure not only requires each table to have a clustered index, but also [disallows `DROP INDEX` for clustered indices.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336293.aspx)

Now I have a table which erroneously has a clustered index on column `A` and I want it to have a clustered index on column `B` instead.

How do I create a clustered index on another column if dropping a clustered index is not allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

You'll have to create a new table with the same structure and correct clustered index, insert the data, drop the old table, and rename the new table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can rebuild indexes in Navicat for SQL connected to Azure.